# Double.ToString() -- Format specifier to "multiply" by million?

Tags: c#, .net, format

Is there a custom format specifier that multiply a number per either 1000 or 1000,000? For example, given `<some specifier>` custom specifier:

```
double value = 1;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,##0<somespecifier>", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 1,000,000
```

This will basically be the opposite of
",," custom specifier:

```
double value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,##0,,", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 1,235
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not something like that built in but you could easily create an extension method to do just that:

```
public static class DoubleExtensions
{
    public static string ToMillionString(this double value)
    {
        return (value * 1000000.0).ToString("#,##0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

And usage would be as follows:

```
double value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToMillionString());
```

Answer (score 1):

The "‰" Custom Specifier does it, but it also adds the '%' symbol...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierPerMille